# How can I calculate the position of a SVG text on a path in Perl?

Tags: perl, svg

I want to extract text from a SVG graphic, and I need to get the texts in the correct order (from left to right). I use an XPath expression to find a all `text` nodes, then use [Image::SVG::Transform](http://search.cpan.org/~colink/Image-SVG-Transform-0.07/lib/Image/SVG/Transform.pm) to calculate the actual position of the text. This works fine for regular text and rotated text.

Now I have text on a path, and I cannot find a Perl module to do the calculations for me. I'd rather not do them on my own, given that I have no clue about SVG internals.

What Perl module can I use to calculate the start position of a text on a path?

Example:

```
<g id="g3426" transform="rotate(180,320.57846,970.1288)">
  <ellipse ry="38.88921" rx="34.891293" cy="1007.3622" cx="373.91425" id="path3887-6"/>
  <text>
     <textPath xlink:href="#path3887-6">
       <tspan dx="71.785721 0 0 -3.5714285">Text on ellipse</tspan>
     </textPath>
  </text>
</g>
```

Comment: Maybe you could try [SVG](https://metacpan.org/pod/SVG#text) module which has a text method.

Comment: @carlosn that module is for creating SVG and the method is for adding text. The OP wants to find the position of text in an existing image.